# Time reversal acting on Lorentz multiplets

Tags: special-relativity, time-reversal-symmetry

Given a finite dimensional multiplet of the Lorentz group $(A,B)$, let's use the notation $|A,a,B,b\rangle$ to denote the vector, how does time reversal $T$ act on this?

I know that $T$ acts on $\vec{A}=(\vec{J}+i\vec{K})/2$ and $\vec{B}=(\vec{J}-i\vec{K})/2$ the following way

$$T\vec{A}T^{-1}=-\vec{A}, \quad T\vec{B}T^{-1}=-\vec{B}$$

So my assumption would be that $T$ acts just like it would acting on a multiplet of spatial angular momentum.

$$T|A,a,B,b\rangle=i^{2(a+b)}|A,-a,B,-b\rangle$$

Up to some phase. Is this correct?

Comment: What are the vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ supposed to be?

Comment: $\vec{A}=(\vec{J}+i\vec{K})/2$ and $\vec{B}=(\vec{J}-i\vec{K})/2$, where $\vec{J}$ is the generator of rotations and $\vec{K}$ is the generator of boosts.

Comment: A minor comment. *States* live in the Hilbert space of the theory which carries one unitary representation of the Poincaré group, all such representations are infinite-dimensional. On the other hand the *fields* take values in finite-dimensional spaces carrying non-unitary representations of the Lorentz group. The whole point is that the Lorentz group, being non-compact, has no finite-dimensional unitary representations. All I want to say here that calling elements of the $(A,B)$ representations states can be misleading.

Comment: @Gold I agree the word *state* is a bit misleading, I changed it to vector.